# Storing value of a cell in another excel document by button click

Tags: vba, excel, button

I'm totally new on StackOverflow and on coding itself, I have only so little knowledge so don't be hard on me :)

What is going on: 
I have a document stored at `C:\Program\Program.xlsm` called `Program.xlsm`
It has different sheets, one of them is Objects - it retreives objects from another file stored at `C:\Program\Objects.xlsx`.

The `Program.xlsm` also has a sheet called "Calculate", which has a cell C6 with list data validation and an autocomplete function, yet other values, not the ones in list are also possible.

What I want to do is:
If  the `Sheet("Calculate").Range("C6").Text` is not already at the `Objects.xlsx`, I want it to be added by a click of a button. I added the button, and added a VBA code:

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim c As Range
Dim dupFound As Boolean
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim wbk1 As Workbook
Dim str As String
Set str = ActiveSheet.Range("C6").Text
Set wbk1 = Workbooks.Open("C:\Program\Objects.xlsx")
dupFound = False
lastRow = wbk1.Worksheets("Objects").Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

For Each c In wbk1.Worksheets("Objects").Range("$B$2:$B$" & lastRow)
    Debug.Print c.Value
    If c.Value = str Then
        dupFound = True
        MsgBox "The object already exists"
        Exit For
    End If
Next c

If dupFound = False Then
    Cells(lastRow + 1, "B").Value = str
End If
End Sub
```

Just a reminder: I am a total newbie at coding, so don't be hard on me :) Thanks!

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: I get object required error and then  Public Sub CommandButton1_Click() highlighted.

Comment: Can you run your code step by step, and see how far you can get?

Answer (score 1):

The main issue here is that in this line

```
Cells(lastRow + 1, "B").Value = str
```

you didn't specify in which workbook and worksheet the cell is. Always specify a worksheet, otherwise Excel guesses the worksheet and Excel might guess something else than you.

The second issue is that a string `Dim str As String` is not an object and therefore needs no `Set` in `Set str = ActiveSheet.Range("C6").Text`

Also I recommend to use the [`WorksheetFunction.Match` Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheetfunction-match-method-excel) to check if a value is already in column B. This should be much faster then looping through every cell.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim str As String
    str = ActiveSheet.Range("C6").Text

    Dim wbk1 As Workbook
    Set wbk1 = Workbooks.Open("C:\Program\Objects.xlsx")

    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = wbk1.Worksheets("Objects").Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

    Dim FoundRow As Long
    FoundRow = 0 'initialize

    'try to match the string with worksheets Objects column B
    On Error Resume Next
    FoundRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(str, wbk1.Worksheets("Objects").Range("B:B"), 0)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If FoundRow = 0 Then 'if nothing matched FoundRow is still 0 otherwise FoundRow contains the row number of the match
        wbk1.Worksheets("Objects").Cells(lastRow + 1, "B").Value = str
    Else
        MsgBox "The object already exists in row " & FoundRow
    End If 
End Sub
```

Comment: I get an object required error and then 
      Public Sub CommandButton1_Click()  
highlighted. It's the same error as before.

Comment: @IgnasAnfalovas See my edit: `str` is no object therefore you must not use `Set`. If this answered your question please mark it as solution.